# How can I pass date value to WebAPI from Angular Client?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-service, angular-ngmodel

I'm using a dynamic value to pass data from database. I'm not sure how to pass the value from the client to the server to get the expected data result.
Here the WebAPI Ctrl:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<getAllDayReps_Result> GetRepsByDate(DateTime datum)
{
   //var dayReps = db.getAllDayReps(new DateTime(2014,05,13)).AsQueryable();
    var dayReps = db.getAllDayReps(datum).AsQueryable();

   return dayReps;
}
```

When I'm testing the commented static value, then it works fine and I'm getting the data from date 2014-05-13. But with the dynamic value I don't get data from the database.

Angular Ctrl:

```
   //Button Send
    $scope.sending = function (sel) {
       $scope.selected = new Date(sel);

       $scope.repDay = ResourceService.ds021.query({
           'datum': $scope.selected
       });
    };
```

Service for REST:

```
return {
  ds021: $resource(baseUrl + '/api/qr_ds021/:Id', {
       Id: '@Id'
  }, {})
};
```

View:

```
<div>
  <input type="date" ng-model="selected" />
  <button type="button" ng-click="sending(selected)">Send</button>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><a href="">F_1 </a></th>
            <th><a href="">F_2 </a></th>
            <th><a href="">F_3 </a></th>
            <th><a href="">F_4 </a></th>
            <th><a href="">F_5 </a></th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="rep in repDay>
            <td>{{ rep.datum }}</td>
            <td>{{ rep.isin }}</td>
            <td>{{ rep.NameId }}</td>
            <td>{{ rep.time_quot }}</td>
            <td>{{ rep.num_quot }}</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
....
```

How you can see I'm typing an value in the input field. The ngModel value will sending with the button "send" to the service. But something is wrong in the service and I don't know what..

---

EDIT:
Here is the method from the Context.tt:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<getAllDayReps_Result> getAllDayReps(Nullable<System.DateTime> datumOut)
{
    var datumOutParameter = datumOut.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("DatumOut", datumOut) :
        new ObjectParameter("DatumOut", typeof(System.DateTime));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<getAllDayReps_Result>("getAllDayReps", datumOutParameter);
}
```

Comment: if you are getting a value in one condition on the server and not getting a value on the other condition, then it seems that the issue is with the server, and the client side code is irrelevant.  Perhaps we can help better if you post the `getAllDayReps(datum)` server method.

Comment: The server wouldn't be able to hit this Route you have listed if it were not receiving data from the client.  However, it is possible that the data being received isn't in the right format, and the server method may be returning 0 results from the query.  Have you used a debugger or console logs to verify the format of the data the method is receiving?

Comment: @Claies I've added my post above... But from the serverside it can't be contains errors because when I'm using the static value then I get the right data from the database to my angular app.. I think the mistake is on the client side. the serverside doesn't get the date value from the client.

Comment: ok, so again, have you verified with the debugger that this method is indeed the one that is being called, and checked to see if the value being received on the server is one that actually makes sense?

Comment: @Claies No, I didn't... how to do this?

Comment: the easiest way would probably be to set a break point on the server at the `var dayReps = db.getAllDayReps(datum).AsQueryable();` and when the breakpoint is triggered, examine the value of `dayReps`.

Comment: @Claies It can't achieve the breakpoint... But how is the generally definition for passing data from angular client to server side WebAPI?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand enough about what is going on in your code to help you here at this point.